# What is the best way to translate JavaScript literal strings in Assetic assets?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony2 to develop a application that is to be translatable. The application has Assetic enabled to minify and combine `*.js` and `*.css` files. However, I have a jQuery plugin I wrote, that has literal strings in it. For example, consider the following code:

```js
       $('<p>Are you sure you want to proceed?</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Yes" : function() {
                    // ...
                },
                "No" : function() {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

In the above snippet, "Are you sure...", "Yes" and "No" will always be English, and I can't use Twig templating in the .js file to translate it using something like: `{{ "yes"|trans }}`

What I want to know is, what would be the best way to use Twig to leverage the built in Symfony2 translation mechanism, to translate the literal strings in my JS scripts.

Is there a way to create for example: `myscript.js.twig` files?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is there a way to create for example: myscript.js.twig files?

It seems a bad idea.

---

You can check https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaExposeTranslationBundle

or create it yourself, for example include this in your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var translations = {
       // ... 
       'yes' : {{ 'yes' | trans }},
       // ...
    }
</script>
```

then if your javascript file is included just before `</body>` you can use `translations` variable in it.

Comment: You should surround `{{ 'yes' | trans }}` with quotes or this will throw an error.

Comment: put your translation yaml into json converter ;)

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution, tested on Symfony 4 and 5.

First, we create a controller that will create a JavaScript file with all the translations according to the current locale:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

/**
 * Translation controller.
 */
class TranslationController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/translation.js", name="translation")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $locale = $request->getLocale();
        $file   = __DIR__.'/../../translations/messages.'.$locale.'.yaml';
        $parsed = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));

        $translations = $this->renderView(
            'translation/translation.js.twig', 
            array(
                'json' => json_encode($parsed)
            )
        );

        return new Response($translations, 200,
            array('Content-Type' => 'text/javascript')
        );
    }
}
```

Then we create a Twig template to render the response:

```
{# /templates/translation/translation.js.twig) #}

var trans = JSON.parse('{{ json|raw }}');
```

We place our dynamically generated translation file in the template before other assets:

```html
script src="{{ path('translation') }}"></script>
```

For sample translation file /translations/messages.pl.yaml:

```yaml
projects: Projekty
medium: Średnio
month:
  january: Styczeń
  february: Luty
```

We can display our translation in any JavaScript file:

```js
console.log(trans['month']['january']);
console.log(trans['medium']);
```

I hope it will be useful to someone.

Comment: There are good ideas here, but also issues. This should be generated ahead of time, not on every request. Also, something should be done to take into account caching, as any request to a `text/javascript` file would be cached. So on generation the cache key should be updated. A companion twig function to deal with this would help. Still, a nice idea nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching something to [make twig.js work with translations](http://loige.co/integrating-twig-js-and-bazingajstranslationbundle/) which seems to me like the best solution. Still searching though.

In the meantime, I'm using this [jsgettext](https://github.com/adrienrn/jsgettext) which is a gettext implementation in Javascript, by Joshua I. Miller. I've uploaded back to github since the original repo is down.

```
<script language="javascript" src="/path/LC_MESSAGES/myDomain.json"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/path/Gettext.js"></script>
```

You load your translation files into your DOM and jsgettext can parse it:

```
function _(msgid) { return gt.gettext(msgid); }

alert(_("some string"));
```

To get the path of your translation files from Symfony, you'll have to make some php/twig extension around the Translator service but it works great without duplicating your translation resources.